# ANDROID: Phone is slow when setting button backgrounds as an image from drawable

Tags: java, android

Basically title.

I have made a small game, and every time the player moves, I want the board to be reset and created from then new data. Here is the code I have tried to get to work.

```
    mustache = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.moustache));
    greenHairedPotato = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.greenhairedpotato));
    purpleHairedPotato = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.purplehairedpotato));
    redHairedPotato = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redhairedpotato));
    yellowHairedPotato = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yellowhairedpotato));
    angryWall = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.angrywall));
    blueSpace = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bluespace));
```

This is the code I use for all the drawables. The code to call it to the buttons is like this to clear to board:

```
public void clearBoard(int lX, int lY) {
    Button temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++){
            temp = (Button)findViewById(buttons[i][j]);
            temp.setBackground(blueSpace);
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I can set the buttons that are user oriented as such, or change other buttons. However, the time it takes for the images to be cleared and the user to be displayed is usually over a second.

Any help would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Save the Button variables somewhere so you don't have to call findViewById every time you need them

Answer (score 0):

two suggestions

1. make sure you are decoding the bitmaps only once (save the
   references and don't create them on each clearBoard
2. use ImageButton instead of Image so you don't need to decode your image resource into bitmap